# send multiple images via file transfer plugin ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

i'm working on app witch i need to send multiple images,

and i wonder if there is any way to send multiple images via file transfer plugin,

this my code:

```
  const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
  }

  this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData2) => {
    this.imageURI2 = imageData2;
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

upload

```
  const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
      fileKey: 'file',
        fileName: 'name.jpg',
        headers: {
          Connection: "close"
        }
    }
      options.chunkedMode = false;

      if(this.imageURI1 != null){
        fileTransfer.upload(this.imageURI1, 
   'https://test.test.com/uplaodphoto.php', options)
        .then((data) => {
          alert("success");
          this.imageFileName1 = 
   "https://test.test.com/images/name.jpg"

        }, (err) => {
          alert("error"+JSON.stringify(err));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

User Image Picker Plugin [Cordova Image Picker](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/image-picker/)

Usage:

```
    import { ImagePicker } from '@ionic-native/image-picker';


    constructor(private imagePicker: ImagePicker) { }

export class YourPage {
   pickImages(){
     this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then((results) => {
       for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
          this.imageUpload(results[i])
      }
    }, (err) => { });
}

    // Upload Image function. 

    imageUpload(path) {
      const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
      let options: FileUploadOptions = {
          fileKey: 'image',
          fileName: '.png',
          chunkedMode: false,
          //mimeType: "image/jpeg",
        }

        fileTransfer.upload(path, 'https://api.com/image-upload', options)
          .then((data) => {
          console.log(data+" Uploaded Successfully");
          let res = JSON.parse(data.response);
          if (res.success == true) {

          }
          this.loader.dismiss();

        }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);

        });
    }
}
```